# Javascript replace isn't working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm working on a greasemonkey script, but the str.replace function isn't working.

I'm trying to disable the onmousedown functions for Google searches, my thought was that by replacing that with nothing, it would just get rid of it.

Here's the code they're using.

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&amp;rct=j&amp;q=&amp;esrc=s&amp;source=web&amp;cd=5&amp;ved=0CFIQFjAE&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fswengineeringnotebook.blogspot.com%2F2010%2F01%2Fjquery-disable-default-event.html&amp;ei=O0nJTqeKOeaosQKMyoBk&amp;usg=AFQjCNHcR98HxCj8kdeVLlBiADbelsvEgw" class="l" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','5','AFQjCNHcR98HxCj8kdeVLlBiADbelsvEgw','','0CFIQFjAE')">My Software Engineering Notebook: <em>JQuery Disable Default</em> Event</a>
```

As you can see, they've got the onmousedown in their links.

Here's what I'm using to get rid of it.

```
$('body').text().replace(/onmousedown=\"return rwt\(.*?\)\"/gi, "");
```

I've also tried redefining the rwt function with just "return false;" but that also seems to have no effect.

Any ideas on how to make this would would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: So you want to get rid of certain `onmousedown` attributes? Trust me, you don't want to serialize the DOM to do this. To manipulate the DOM, you use... well... DOM manipulation functions.

Comment: What would you recommend then?

Comment: The solution proposed by Gustav.

Comment: Lol, thanks. His removeAttr solution works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if I got your question, but as you tagged with jQuery and You want to remove onmousedown attribute, I'd do:

```
$("a").removeAttr('onmousedown');
```

If it does not work, maybe You could try unbinding:

```
$("a").unbind('mousedown');
```

Comment: The first one works... the second one doesn't (`.unbind()` only works for handlers bound with `.bind()`... or the shorthand methods like `.mousedown()`).

Comment: This works perfectly. Thanks :) Didn't know about removeAttr. I'll mark this as answered when it lets me!

Comment: Just to make it complete: `replace` function does not replace the var its reference. So, `text.replace('a','b');'` replaces a for b's, but `text` var remains untouched. If you need `text` to be modified, you need to do `text = text.replace('a','b');'`